# How to add the value object keys in reduce method

Tags: javascript

Please forgive me if this is basic or has been asked elsewhere before. I'm very new to programming and would appreciate useful resources where I can learn as well as answers.

Let's say this is my object.

```
const obj = [
{store_id: 1, price: 0.55},
{store_id: 1, price: 0.25},
{store_id: 2, price: 0.2},
{store_id: 2, price: 0.25}
]
```

I'm using the reduce and find methods to create an array of objects with unique store_id's however I would also like to add the price of those store_ids that match and currently it only returns the first price that appears.

**Current method:**

```
const result = obj.reduce((items, item) => items.find(x => x.store_id === item.store_id) ? [...items] : [...items, item], [])
```

**Desired result:**

```
[
{store_id: 1, price: 0.80},
{store_id: 2, price: 0.45}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the objects by `store_id` and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the list of grouped objects:

```js
const arr = [
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.55},
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.25},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.2},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.25}
]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const { store_id } = item;
  const prev = acc[store_id];
  acc[store_id] = prev ? { ...prev, price: prev.price+item.price } : {...item};
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const obj = [
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.55},
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.25},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.2},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.25}
]

const output = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.store_id])
    acc[cur.store_id] = { store_id: cur.store_id, price: cur.price };
  else acc[cur.store_id].price += cur.price;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(output));
```

Answer (score 1):

Some answers have already been submitted but I'd like to add a way that is (at least to me) a bit simpler.

First of all, the reason why your solution does not work is that destructuring an object does not sum the price key, it just picks 1.

If I had to do this, I would split this into 2 phases.

1. Calculate the sum for every id
2. Format to your required solution.

```js
const arr = [
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.55},
  {store_id: 1, price: 0.25},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.2},
  {store_id: 2, price: 0.25}
]

// Calculate the total for every store_id
const sums = arr.reduce((sums, item) => {
  if (sums[item.store_id] == null) {
    sums[item.store_id] = [item.price];
  } else {
    sums[item.store_id] += item.price;
  }
  return sums;
}, 0);

// Format
const storeIds = Object.keys(sums);
let result = [];
for (const storeId of storeIds) {
  result.push({
    store_id: storeId,
    price: sums[storeId]
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a compact `reduce()` option utilizing the new [logical nullish assignment operator `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator#Processing_and_then_returning).

```js
const result = obj.reduce((items, { price, ...item }) => (
  (items[item.store_id] ??= { ...item, price: 0 }).price += price, items), {});

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

```html
<script>
const obj = [
  { store_id: 1, price: 0.55 },
  { store_id: 1, price: 0.25 },
  { store_id: 2, price: 0.2 },
  { store_id: 2, price: 0.25 }
];
</script>
```